# Is it possible to find solutions to $C=e^{a*x}(A*\cosh(b*x)+B*\sinh(b*x))$

Tags: transcendental-equations

I need to solve a problem in which I find an equation like:

$$C=e^{a*x}(A*\cosh(b*x)+B*\sinh(b*x))$$

I would like to express $x$ in function of $C,a,b,A,B$.

However I am starting to wonder if it is simply possible to find analytic solution to this... Is it a kind of non solvable analytically transcendent equation ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

put $$A= M\sinh(b\,c)\quad B=M\cosh(b\,c)$$ 
which invert to
 $$B^2-A^2=M^2 \quad \tanh(bc)=a/B$$

Then use the fact that
$\sinh(x+y)=\sinh(x)\cos(y)+\sinh(y) \cosh(x)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I follow you method I would end up with $\frac{C}{M}=e^{ax}sinh(b(c+x))$ but then I don't see either how this can be solved. If I expand I could have on the right handside a sum involving two exponentials which I don't see how it can be solved analytically but maybe I'm confused

Comment: You are right, and I don't see how further you can go analytically .

Comment: See related [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431847) solution after substituting $b(c+x)\to x$